# How to validate ASPNET AJAX installation

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

How can I validate that my ASPNET AJAX installation is correct.

I have Visual Studio 2008 and had never previously installed any AJAX version.

My UpdatePanel is nto working within IIS6, although it works ok within Visual Studio's web server. The behaviour I get is as if the UpdatePanel doesnt exist at all - i.e. it reverts back to 'normal' ASPX type behavior.

I tried installing AJAX from [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en) followed by an IISRESET yet still it is still not working properly.

What can I check to diagnose the problem?

**Update:** When running within Visual Studio (Cassini) I get the following 3 requests shown in Fiddler:

```
http://localhost:1105/RRStatistics/WebResource.axd?d=k5J0oI4tNNc1xbK-2DAgZg2&t=633564733834698722

http://localhost:1105/RRStatistics/ScriptResource.axd?d=N8BdmNpXVve13PiOuRcss0GMKpoTBFsi7UcScm-WmXE9jw5qOijeLDcIyiOsSQZ4k3shu0R2ly5WhH2vI_IbNVcTbxej1dkbdYFXrN6c7Qw1&t=ffffffff867086f6

http://localhost:1105/RRStatistics/ScriptResource.axd?d=N8BdmNpXVve13PiOuRcss0GMKpoTBFsi7UcScm-WmXE9jw5qOijeLDcIyiOsSQZ4AsqNeJVXGSf6sCcCp1QK0jdKTlbRqIN1LFVP8w6R0lJ_vbk-CfopYINgjYsHpWfP0&t=ffffffff867086f6
```

but when I run within IIS i only get this single request :

```
http://www.example.com/RRStatistics/ScriptResource.axd?d=f_uL3BYT2usKhP7VtSYNUxxYRLVrX5rhnXUonvvzSEIc1qA5dLOlcdNr9xlkSQcnZKyBHj1nI523o9DjxNr45hRpHF7xxC5WlhImxu9TALw1&t=ffffffff867086f6
```

Now the second request in Cassini contains a javascript file with 'partial rendering' as one of the first comments. I'm sure this is the source of the problem, but I cannot figure out why in IIS i dont get the other requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for any JavaScript errors. Sometimes the JavaScript required for the UpdatePanel to work fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this myself, but I found several forum postings recommending the following

> Try and add the following to your
>   web.config
>
> within
>   <system.webServer><handlers>
>
> <add verb="GET"
>   path="ScriptResource.axd"
>   type="Microsoft.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler"
>   validate="false" />

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to check your web.config. You could for example create an new Ajax enabled ASP.NET website from Visual Studio. This will generate a correct web.config. Copy over all non-ajax sections from your existing web.config and you're set. This worked for me.

-Edoode